# How to share data from an asyncio object to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and I just thought of doing some threading\process to enhance my knowledge on the subject but I got stuck on how to code my idea.

I am thinking that I will have some async process that takes a bit of time so I have coded it like this:

**async_controller.py**

```
import asyncio

async def get_something():
    #io intensive task
    sample_data = <do something here>
    await asyncio.sleep(0)

def start():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(get_something())
    loop.run_forever()
```

And I am simulating a server that needs to get the data from my async_controller.

**server.py**

```
def serve():
    #get async_controller sample_data
    #gets called simultaneously

def start_server():
    #start the server
    #
```

And this is my main class which starts both process

**main.py**

```
import async_controller
import server

def main():
    async_controller.start()
    server.start_server()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am stuck on two things:

1. How do I share data between my async_controller and my server?
2. My async controller should retrieve the data first before my server
   starts serving in the serve() method?

Any thoughts on how to do this thing in Python?  I want to deepen my knowledge so I am trying to gather ideas from experts here.

Comment: [pipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pipes.html) are usually a solution to this type of problem - set up one end of the pipe in one process, set up the end in the other, and both sides can read/write into them at their convenience.

Comment: You say “thread\process”—are these supposed to be separate processes?